# Inexplicable linebreaks in xml file that cannot be removed

Tags: php, sql, xml

So I have a sql database that generates an xml file. This xml file gets put on a webserver and then parsed by a php file. Unfortunately randomly sometimes there will be a line break in the xml file that causes it to be unable to be parsed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCF4N.jpg

As you can see from line 12-14. There is a linebreak. But I have no idea why. And I even wrote a script to remove carriage returns and newline characters but the linebreaks still remain. Anyone have any ideas?

```
$inputXML = file_get_contents("ukso.xml");
$fixedXML = str_replace("\r","",$inputXML);
$fixedXML = str_replace("\n","",$inputXML);
$fixedXML = str_replace("  ","",$inputXML);
$myFile = "ukso.xml";
print $fixedXML;
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $fixedXML);
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code to remove linebreaks is broken.  make the following changes:

```
$inputXML = file_get_contents("ukso.xml");
$fixedXML = str_replace("\r","",$inputXML);
$fixedXML = str_replace("\n","",$fixedXML); // note: reference the correct variable here
$fixedXML = str_replace("  ","",$fixedXML); // and here.
$myFile = "ukso.xml";
print $fixedXML;
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $fixedXML);
fclose($fh);
```

The code as you have it is only trimming out double spaces.

Comment: Hmm, I got it down to this    <?php

$inputXML = file_get_contents("ukso.xml");
$fixedXML = str_replace("\r","",$inputXML);

$myFile = "ukso.xml";
print $fixedXML;
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $fixedXML);
fclose($fh);
?> but still no luck

Comment: Chris's point is that you're not using all your str_replaces.  You have to run str_replace on the new variable ($fixedXML) after the first call.  In your code you're running it on the same original variable over and over again.  Try Chris's code in place of yours.

Comment: Or try $fixedXML = str_replace("\r","",str_replace("\n","",str_replace("  ","",$inputXML)));

Comment: There are cases where linebreaks have to be replaced by spaces. It depends on structure of your XML

Comment: Got it to work thanks! I just used this instead $fixedXML = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), null, $inputXML);

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using notepad++

Go into view-show symbol-show all characters.  That will tell you exactly what characters there are in the file.

It's possible that the line breaks are also due to the line being too long otherwise.  XML files are usually designed to have line breaks at the end of tags, and you may be running into a situation where the line length is too long somewhere in one of the programs. (Often they create a fixed buffer and read in as much as possible, and if it's too long the program will chop the line)

Comment: Thanks! After showing symbols, it displayed a CR at those positions. Which I am assuming carriage return. So I guess the issue is with my php script? But what could be wrong with it?